# Displaying decimal numbers uniformly on PowerShell 5.1 and 7.3.4

Tags: powershell

On Windows PowerShell version 5.1, if I create a `pscustomobject`, it is displayed as follows:

[image]

However, on PowerShell version 7.3.4 on Ubuntu, it displays as follows:

[image]

Note the three decimal places.

## Workaround

I'd like to display the number with no decimal places.

It seems like this is a workaround:

[image]

## Question

I'd like to display `decimal` values in a table without the decimal places in a cross-platform and cross-version manner.

Is the above the best approach?

Comment: Is this mainly for displaying the data in your console or are you planning to export it later? `Export-Csv` would `ToString` it for you for example.

Comment: In this case, it's mostly for display in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) is the right approach, but you can simplify it as follows:

```bash
[pscustomobject] @{
  abc = [decimal] 12
} | Format-Table @{ Expression='abc'; FormatString='N0' }
```

- Using the name of a *property* as a *string* as the value of the  `Expression` entry tells PowerShell to not only use that property's *value*, but also to use its name as the *column name*.

  - That is, unless you want to give the column a name that *differs* from a referenced property's name, there is no need for a separate `Label` (aka `Name`) entry.
- `FormatString` allows you to specify a .NET format string that is applied to what the `Expression` entry evaluates to.

  - `N0` is a [standard numeric .NET format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) that applies number formatting  `N` with `0` decimal places.
  - Note that thousands-grouping is still applied, however (e.g., `123000` becomes `123,000`, in cultures that use `,` as the grouping char.).
    To prevent that, use `G0` instead.

---

**Background information:**

- With respect to *default output formatting* of *tables* (implicit or explicit use of [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)), [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) introduced a change to how numeric types that are capable of storing *fractional* numbers (`[double]`, `[decimal]`, and the - rarely used - `[single]`) are formatted:

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, `.ToString()` formatting was applied, whereas `N` number formatting is now applied to instances of said types, which results in a *fixed* number of decimal places implied by that format, and, unfortunately, the number of decimal places is not only potentially *culture-dependent*, but in effect also *differs across platforms for a GIVEN culture*, due to different localization libraries being employed - see [this comment on GitHub issue #81853](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/81853#issuecomment-1424974267) for details.
  - The *rationale* for that change was that the Windows PowerShell `.ToString()` approach resulted in numbers that (a) could vary wildly in terms of the decimal places used and (b) the numbers weren't aligned by the decimal mark.
    Run `[pscustomobject] @{ Num = 1/9 }, [pscustomobject] @{ Num = 2.1 }` in a Windows PowerShell session to see the problem.
  - See [GitHub issue #19107](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19107) for an extensive discussion of this change, in the course of which two *potential enhancements* were discussed:

    - Making `Format-Table -AutoSize` use `.ToString()`-formatting again, but *with alignment on the decimal mark*.
    - Situationally *omitting* all-`0` decimal places and the decimal mark while *still aligning on the decimal mark* of numbers that *do* have non-zero decimal places.
      However, this would require a change in .NET itself, which as of v7.x doesn't support that - see [this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19107#issuecomment-1423177047) on the linked GitHub issue for details.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you! Tested and works well in both versions.

Comment: If you're curious, I caught this issue by running [this script](https://github.com/dharmatech/treasury-gov-tga-top.ps1) on Ubuntu with PS 7.3.4.